# counting number of entries in a month

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an order table, and it has a datetime column called order_date.  I want to count the number of orders for each month in 2009.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select month(order_date) as orderMonth, count(*) as orderCount
from order
where year(order_date) = 2009
group by month(order_date)
order by month(order_date)
```

For reference, see [`month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813(SQL.90).aspx) and [`year`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313(SQL.90).aspx) commands in Transact-SQL.

Comment: thanks.  I was trying what kaleb below suggested,but it refused to recognize orderMonth as a column!

Comment: The use of the functions YEAR() and MONTH() is likely to render any maybe existing index on order_date unusuable. You will run into performance issues once the table grows.

Comment: thanks for that comment.  however this is a one time deal only.  a query that someone requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(order_date) AS ordermonth, 
   COUNT(*) AS ordercount 
FROM order 
WHERE YEAR(order_date) = 2009 
GROUP BY ordermonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using some neat DATETIME trick?

```
select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, order_date), 0) AS orderMonth, count(*) as orderCount
from 
    [order]
where 
    order_date >= '2009-01-01'
group by 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, order_date), 0)
order by 
    orderMonth
```